# Removing blank spaces between slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am making a jQuery image slider. The slider is working perfectly fine, but I don't want the white spaces between slides. How can I get rid of them?

```js
window.onload = function slider() {
    $(".slider #1").show("fade", {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 500);
    $(".slider #1").delay(5000).hide("slide", {
        direction: 'left'
    }, 500);

    var sc = $(".slider img").size();
    var count = 2;
    var margin = $(".slider").width();

    setInterval(function() {
        $(".slider #" + count).show("slide", {
            direction: 'right'
        }, 500);
        $(".slider #" + count).delay(5000).hide("slide", {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 500);

        if (count == sc) {
            count = 1;
        } else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }, 6500);
}
```

```css
.img-style {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.slider {
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider img {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row " style="width:100%;margin-left:0px;" id="main">
        <div class="slider" id="slide-for">
            <img id="1" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/1/" />
            <img id="2" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/2/" />
            <img id="3" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/3/" />
            <img id="4" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/4/" />
            <img id="5" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/5/" />
            <img id="6" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/6/" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

View on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ef1v559/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning does the trick.

```js
window.onload = function slider() {
  
  $(".slider #1").show("fade", {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 500);

  var sc = $(".slider img").size();
  var count = 1;
  var margin = $(".slider").width();

  setInterval(function() {
    $(".slider #" + count).toggle("slide", {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 500);

    if (count == sc) {
      count = 1;
    } else {
      count = count + 1;
    }

    $(".slider #" + count).toggle("slide",  {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 500);
  }, 6500);

}
```

```css
.img-style {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.slider {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slider img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row " style="width:100%;margin-left:0px;" id="main">
    <div class="slider" id="slide-for">
      <img id="1" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/1/" />
      <img id="2" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/2/" />
      <img id="3" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/3/" />
      <img id="4" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/4/" />
      <img id="5" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/5/" />
      <img id="6" class="img-style" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/abstract/6/" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.. doing position:absolute it's set on the background of the page and not in the div I want it in the div..

Comment: also if I do absolute positioning I cant make it responsive..can u please help me with this it confusing

Comment: I don't think it's possible to accomplish without absolute positioning to overlay the image elements on top of each other. Otherwise, the animation for the second image is done off-screen and doesn't display until the first image is hidden. That's why you are seeing the blank space between the images when sliding.